# How can I hyper customize the MacBookPro Touch Bar?

Tags: macos, touch-bar

I want my Touch Bar to have:

- Esc
- F1-F12
- Toggle Mute
- Volume Slider
- Screen-Brightness Slider

I don't care if the buttons have to be squished to achieve this. I know you can do some customization through System Preferences > Keyboard > Keyboard, but it doesn't give you much fine control. Is there another interface or maybe even a config file one can use to hyper customize the Touch Bar?

Answer (score 1):

The following options should get your job done

[**My TouchBar My Rules**](https://mtmr.app/)

Source is on [GitHub](https://github.com/Toxblh/MTMR). This [Youtube video](https://youtu.be/spAS3IaxV_Q) explains it's functionality

**Pros**: Free and Open Source, More customizations to touch bar than the next option, Adding Custom gestures ([Instructions](https://github.com/Toxblh/MTMR#custom-gestures)) - It's pretty easy to add custom functionality, All the functions you mentioned: *Esc, F1-F12, Toggle Mute, Volume Slider, Screen-Brightness Slider* are all there as [default presets](https://github.com/Toxblh/MTMR#built-in-button-types) \

**Cons**: I had a hard time installing it but type this `open -e ~/Library/Application\ Support/MTMR/items.json` in the terminal and then you should be good, My friends complain it's buggy in Big Sur but I haven't upgraded yet so no opinions on that.

[**BetterTouchTool**](https://folivora.ai/)

**Pros**: Completly customize the touch bar just like the above app, Wide range of gesture controls for Apple peripheral such as Magic Mouse and Keyboard, Big Sur Native Compatibility.

**Cons**: It's paid , Text Triggers are quite buggy.

I use BetterTouchTool cause it has more customizations for the Magic Mouse and Keyboard but for your requirements, MTMR should do the job in flying colors.

Answer (score 0):

[MTMR](https://github.com/Toxblh/MTMR) , it's free but it does need some editing to get it fully customized